# Is it possible to alias property to a variable in a Powershell pipeline command?

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to create something along the lines of the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -path *.txt* -recurse | $a = $_.Name.Length | Format-Table Name, $a
```

This is a contrived example, but assume that I wanted to make use of `$_Name.Length` several times, but substitute `$1` or `$a` in its place.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Use an intermediate calculated property:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path *.txt* -Recurse | Select-Object *, @{ n='a'; e={ $_.Name.Length } } |  
  Format-Table Name, a
```

Note:

- This uses a *property on the output object* rather than a *variable* to carry the value of interest.
- In doing so, it changes the type of the objects passed through the pipeline to type `[pscustomobject]` - a custom type with the added `a` property. This may or may not be a problem (*not* a problem with piping to `Format-Table`).

---

By contrast, if your plan is to simply process the input objects in a `ForEach-Object` process block anyway, you can simply define a variable inside that block:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path *.txt* -Recurse | ForEach-Object { 
  $a=$_.Name; $a.Substring(0, $a.IndexOf('.txt')) 
}
```

(As an aside: This example command doesn't strictly need a helper variable, because it can more succinctly expressed as:
`Get-ChildItem -Path *.txt* -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $_.Name -replace '\.txt.*$' }`).

Comment: The goal is to use it in existing calculated properties, many of which rely on `$_.Name.Length` without having to type it out repeatedly.

Comment: I'm receiving an error, likely because I am not referencing a variable. I'm trying to take `$_.Name` and bind it to a temp variable -- let's call it `$a` -- so that I can do something like the following: `$a.Substring(0,$a.IndexOf(".apx"))` instead of `$_Name..Substring(0,$_Name.IndexOf(".apx"))`.

Comment: @toolshed: Note that my solution provides the value of interest _as a property value_, not as a _variable_, and that your question asks for a shortcut to `$_.Name.Length`, not `$_.Name`.
I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve, so please update you question with an example command that is truly representative of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @toolshed Maybe it's just an example, but $_.Basename looks easier to me.

Comment: @LotPings: `.BaseName` is generally handy, but look at the wildcard expression: `*.txt*` would also match files such as `file.txt.zip`, in which case `.BaseName` would yield a different result.